# What are this passwords' meaning in Splatter House 3

Tags: sega-genesis, splatterhouse-3

I mean [these ones](http://www.ssega.com/cheat/splatterhouse-3/1580).

Example:

I reached the 6th level (The Mask) with Jennifer (mother) dead and David (son) alive. The game gave me this password: TETUYA. However, this cheat page tells this password corresponds to "The Mask 2" level, like... not specifying death or alive status of anyone, while password for "you reached level 6 with Jennifer dead and David alive" is DEPITN.

In some other pages, passwords which do not have a status for family members are referred as "Level Passwords" while password with family members' statuses are referred as "Stage Passwords".

By playing again, twice, I got two different passwords: URUURU (both dead), and PHENIX (both alive). In contrast to the first time, what I got fit in the "Stage Passwords" category.

My question is: What is the difference between both? What happens with the storyline status when I enter a Level Password instead of a Stage Password?

Answer (score 2):

I found more guides about this over at GameFAQs. The multiple passwords per stage or level (these are synonymous, it's just a bit of internet ambiguity) are used as a rudimentary save-game feature.

There are 6 game states for stage 5, 6, and X. Jennifer is alive, a mindless beast, or dead. David is alive or dead. This gives 18 passwords. Stage 3 and 4 have 3 states for another 6 passwords, while stage 2 has 2 states for another 2.

```
+----------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| jennifer | alive  |        | mindless |        | dead   |        |
| david    | alive  | dead   | alive    | dead   | alive  | dead   |
+----------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| 2        | REISOR | ------ | ------   | ------ | OWDRAT | ------ |
| 3        | ETLBUD | ------ | NAMEPA   | ------ | NAIGEP | ------ |
| 4        | TEKROH | ------ | TABRAE   | ------ | DABHSN | ------ |
| 5        | RUATNC | ELPOEB | HTRACM   | REYALS | NOILCK | TSAEBD |
| 6        | PHENIX | VELGAE | IRTACK   | LILITH | DEPITN | URUURU |
| X        | HARUON | ***    | XASABR   | SECOLQ | SARDNA | LEZAJM |
+----------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

***: This is a special case: the guide lists 5 possible passwords:

```
GOFMTS    HCTERG    NILVED    SORABV    ETIRPS
```

Some testing would be needed as to what the purpose of this is, if there is any. It seems to me these passwords store which stage you **came** from (this may be any of 1,2,3,4, or 5) so that the game knows where to send you after completing stage X. (So there are really multiple of these bonus levels, one per level but the last.)

That hypothesis would mean stage X should really feature even more passwords: while only `HARUON` was listed in the FAQ, there should be at least 5 passwords for that case. At least 4 for `XASABR`, at least 5 or `SARDNA`, etc.

Perhaps the normal stages also track something about stage X, and that's why there are more possible password states?

Comment: And where would the TETUYA password (first time I beat the game, I got this password: for the last level (fight against the mask) when Jennifer was dead, while David was alive) be? I mean: I got that password instead of DEPITN.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't yet been able to find more information. This answer is incomplete. I do have a hypothesis that e.g. 'DEPITN' vs. 'TETUYA' would track some state about stage X. Seems like experimentation would be the only recourse.

Answer (score -1):

yo the only difference is whether jen or david is alive. and depending on which 
will change the cut scenes you get during the next level.

perhaps whats more concerning is the fact that some passwords are the names of
demons from hell. spelt backwards.

Comment: wtf i dunno why i got down voted.. is what i said in anyway untrue? btw aphid theres a total of 6 unique "bonus stage x" you get the bonus stage x after each stage(not 5 or 6) if you complete stage 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 with a fast time i forget the number. BUT if you complete stage 1 or 2 with 3:00 or greater left on the clock you go to a special "stage x" which lets you skip a stage(so you can skip stage 2 or 3 potentially) ive been following this games whole password fiasco since i discovered that easter egg. i believe that all the passwords in the game have been revealed by now.

Comment: i forgot to mention you can only access 2 of the bonus stage x's from passwords. and the times required to reach these stages are different depending on which version you are playing.

Comment: AND keep in mind that you can save jen or david quickly or slow. depending on the speed of their rescue will change your cut scenes and thus a different outcome in the game.

Comment: Howdy overm.  Welcome to Arqade.  I'm not sure why you got downvoted, but it is fine to edit additional information into your post.  Burying relevant information in comments isn't going to help you get upvotes.

Comment: sorry i suck at this interface. and i didnt realize that would be a issue. question what is the relevant information in this post?